# Story about giant ants keeping humans in a zoo

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

This is one of two Science Fictions stories that had excerpts in our readers for school that I still remember. In this one, a kid wakes up and everything is slightly different. By the end of the excerpt, he figures out that he and his family are in a cage at a zoo whose owners have (assumedly incorrectly) identified humans as going extinct. The boy stages an escape, and figures out that the ant-like aliens running the zoo are blind to movement.

I've always wondered what happened in the rest of the story.

Comment: It's probably not _The Cage_ by Bertram Chandler, but I'm just putting this here in case you might have two stories mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

It is almost certainly [Awesome Ants](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Awesome_Ants) short story from book *Still More Tales to Give You Goosebumps* . It was later made into a tv series episode of the same [title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Goosebumps_episodes), from which I remember it.

> It features a child who starts a science project revolving around ants, and the company he purchases from is called Awesome Ants. Not satisfied with regular ant food, he resorts to feeding them other things like hot dogs or worms and this eventually backfires on him. The ants grow to incredible proportions and one of them drags him off. The next thing he knew, he woke up in a world where the roles have switched, where ants are the dominant species and humans are miniature insects.

Comment: Unfortunately, the description is not enough for me to determine whether or not it's the same story. Are the ants aliens? Are they in a cage made up to be a lot like their real life, but slightly off? Is the ground rubbery?

Comment: It's definitely this.

Comment: @trlkly I don't think it is mentioned in tv episode that ants are aliens, but answering other questions - yes and yes. Just watch an episode, then you'll know.

Comment: @Kao, that's enough for me, then. I'm not entirely sure they actually were aliens, or if the kid just thought they were. Interesting that a *Goosebumps* story made it into my school's reader. My main reason for wanting the story was that the excerpt they gave didn't finish the story.

Comment: Sorry. Finally got my hands on the book. This was not it. This was literally in a zoo, and the ant-like creatures could not sense motion. The part where it left off was when they were trying to escape.